# LDAP sudoers sudoHost wildcards

Tags: ldap, sudoers

I'm trying to use "sudoHost" to match a sequence of hostname on sudoers LDAP. Does anybody knows
how to grep for this:

```
1080s.....1089s?
```

I try testing on bash and I don't seem to work.

```
grep  "[1082s-1089s]" devtech
```

I will greatly appreciate any hints
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an openldap sudoers question or a grep question?

If you have the following lines within a file called devtech:

1079s
1080s
1081s
1082s
...
1089s
1090s

And you want to match just those entries you specified, the grep regex would look like this:

```
grep -E '^108[0-9]s$' devtech
```

I included the start (^) and end ($) of line markers just to be absolutely explicit, but you don't strictly need them (unless you're afraid of matching '11085s').

Comment: Hey Sebastian, thank you for your response. I really appreciate it. This is ldap question. The ldap sudoers has a field called "SudoHost" and I'm trying to add multiple hostnames base on the criteria above. Your answer will not work, because I cannot use grep. Thank you

Comment: Pretty sure sudoHost doesn't support regex. https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.ldap.man.html#sudoHost you can use netgroups? https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Netgroup

Comment: Hey Sebastian,  thank you for follow up with me. I will read it and see what I will come up .